# Cocos2d-x - Android - certain images not showing up on certain devices with the same resolution

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, scaling, cocos2d-x-3.0

When developing our Cocos2d-x game for Android, we recently updated it to use only one set of high quality image assets (resolution of 1536 x 2272), rather than multiple sets of image assets for different screen resolutions, and  using Cocos2d-x "setContentScaleFactor" method, allowing it to scale the high quality image accordingly for the target device's screen resolution, like so:

```
resDirOrders.push_back( "ipadhd" );
CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1536, 2272);
director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/frameSize.height);
fileUtils->setSearchPaths(resDirOrders);
```

Strangely, while testing the game, we seem to be noticing that some images, like menu buttons, game logo, game character, show up perfectly, but other images like scrolling backgrounds, splash screen image, don't show up at all.

We thought such issues might end up occurring for devices with untested screen resolutions, but strangely, for an example, some images are completely blank / don't show up on an HTC ONE X (screen resolution: 720 x 1280), but show up perfectly on a first-gen Moto X with the same screen resolution. The same issue was noticed when testing with two Android tablets; some images are completely blank / don't show up on a Lenovo IdeaTab A1000 (screen resolution: 600 x 1024), but show up perfectly on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 with the same screen resolution.

Any idea why this might be happening? Are there other factors we have to be taking into account when using one set of high quality images and scaling them accordingly based on the target device's screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of image sizes.
You are using 1536 x 2272 size of image(s) which would not render on some low resolution phones.

Your have to put images of at-least one more resolution. maybe 50% of size you are currently using.

```
CCSize resourceSize;

if (screenSize.height=>2272)
{
resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1536, 2272);
resDirOrders.push_back( "ipadhd" );
}
else
{
resourceSize = CCSizeMake(768, 1136);
resDirOrders.push_back( "ipad" );
}

director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/frameSize.height);
fileUtils->setSearchPaths(resDirOrders);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Shoaib! sorry, I was travelling and did not have access to the net; yes, the smaller image sizes helped and it finally started working!! Also, what are the guidelines for using "setDesignResolutionSize"? Do I need to use it in this case? or is it a must to always use it?

Comment: I think, you should use setDesignResolutionSize in all cases.